# How to calcuate the beta metrics?

Tags: image-processing, matlab

I am working on Speckle reduction in ultrasound images. I read a paper (snapshot of that paper is included below) where they have used a metric called beta metric which indicates the edge preserving capability of the filters. I tried to implement it using the equation (7) provided in the below snapshot.

[image: Beta Metrics]

This is the code.

```
 %---Beta Calculation
    h = fspecial('laplacian');
    I1 = imfilter(Orig_Image,h);
    I2 = imfilter(Esti_Image,h);
    I_1 = mean2(I1);
    I_2 = mean2(I2);
    metrics.Beta = sum(sum((I1 - I_1).*(I2 - I_2)))./(sqrt(sum(((I1 - I_1).^2).*((I2 - I_2).^2))));
```

**As you can see that the beta value is a single value [1x1] vector in Table 2 inside the snapshot. But when I run my code, I get beta value of size 1x256 for a 256x256 image.
Is my code wrong? How to implement the given equation (7) correctly in MATLAB? Please help.**

Answer (score 1):

The correct code is

```
metrics.Beta = sum(sum((I1 - I_1).*(I2 - I_2)))./(sqrt(sum(sum((I1 - I_1).^2))).*(sum(sum((I2 - I_2).^2))));
```

The reference you have shown is incorrect, reffr paper:

> 2013 August Gregorio - *‘A suitable threshold for speckle reduction in
>   ultrasound images’*,  IEEE transactions on instrumentations and
>   measurement